# Google Apps Script - how to get the deleted row in onEdit script, or onDelete?

Tags: google-apps-script

I need to get the row number and the content for the deleted row in onEdit trigger script. or is there an onDelete function?

Basically, when user deletes one row or a range of rows, the script should be notified the range deleted, in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. There's a feature request opened regarding this, you may want to *star* it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.

[Issue 1363: Add trigger for spreadsheet column or row operations](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1363)

Answer (score 3):

If user deletes one cell this works:

```
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.value==e.source.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue()) {
        //Things to do for normal edition
    } else {
        //Things to do if cell was deleted
        deleted_range = e.range
    }
}
```

I'm not shure if that's the right solution but works fine until now. For multiple cells i can't find a solution yet :/